# Performance of joining on multiple columns with potential NULL values

Tags: postgresql

Lets say we have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    record_id SERIAL,
    column_1 INTEGER,
    column_2 INTEGER,
    column_3 INTEGER,
    price NUMERIC
);
```

With the following data

```
INSERT INTO my_table (column_1, column_2, column_3, price) VALUES
(1,    NULL,    1,    54.99),
(1,    NULL,    1,    69.50),
(NULL, 2,       2,    54.99),
(NULL, 2,       2,    69.50),
(3,    3,       NULL, 54.99),
(3,    3,       NULL, 69.50);
```

Now we do something like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_aggregations AS
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS aggregation_id,
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3;
```

What I want to do now is assign an aggregation_id to each record_id in my_table. Now because I have NULL values I cant simply join by `t1.column_1 = t2.column_1` because `NULL = NULL` is NULL and so the join will exclude these records.

Now I know that I should use something like this

```
SELECT
    t.record_id,
    agg.aggregation_id
FROM my_table t
JOIN my_table_aggregations agg ON 
(
    ((t.column_1 IS NULL AND agg.column_1 IS NULL) OR t.column_1 = agg.column_1) AND
    ((t.column_2 IS NULL AND agg.column_2 IS NULL) OR t.column_2 = agg.column_2) AND
    ((t.column_3 IS NULL AND agg.column_3 IS NULL) OR t.column_3 = agg.column_3)
);
```

The problem here is that I am dealing with hundreds of millions of records and having an OR in the join seems to take forever to run.

There is an alternative, which is something like this

```
SELECT
    t.record_id,
    agg.aggregation_id
FROM my_table t
JOIN my_table_aggregations agg ON 
(
    COALESCE(t.column_1, -1) = COALESCE(agg.column_1, -1) AND
    COALESCE(t.column_2, -1) = COALESCE(agg.column_2, -1) AND
    COALESCE(t.column_3, -1) = COALESCE(agg.column_3, -1)
);
```

But the problem with this is that I am assuming there is no value in any of those columns which is -1.

Do note, this is an example which I am well aware I can use `DENSE_RANK` to get the same result. So lets pretend that this isn't an option.

Is there some crazy awesome way to get around having to use `COALESCE` but keeping the performance it has over using the correct way of the `OR`? I run tests, and the `COALESCE` is over 10 times faster than the `OR`.

I am running this on a Greenplum database so I am not sure if this performance difference is the same on a standard Postgres database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some thinking, I decided the best approach this this is to dynamically find a value for each column that can be used as the second param in a `COALESCE` join. The function is rather long, but it does what I need and more importantly, this way keeps the `COALESCE` performance, the only down side is getting the `MIN` values is an additional time cost, but we are talking a minute.

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.get_null_join_int_value
(
    left_table_schema TEXT, 
    left_table_name TEXT, 
    left_table_columns TEXT[],
    right_table_schema TEXT, 
    right_table_name TEXT, 
    right_table_columns TEXT[],
    output_table_schema TEXT,
    output_table_name TEXT
) RETURNS TEXT AS
$$
DECLARE
    colum_name TEXT;
    sql TEXT;
    complete_sql TEXT;
    full_left_table TEXT;
    full_right_table TEXT;
    full_output_table TEXT;
BEGIN

    /*****************************
        VALIDATE PARAMS
    ******************************/

    -- this section validates all of the function parameters ensuring that the values that cannot be NULL are not so
    -- also checks for empty arrays which is not allowed and then ensures both arrays are of the same length
    IF (left_table_name IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'left_table_name cannot be NULL';
    ELSIF (left_table_columns IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'left_table_columns cannot be NULL';
    ELSIF (right_table_name IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'right_table_name cannot be NULL';
    ELSIF (right_table_columns IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'right_table_columns cannot be NULL';
    ELSIF (output_table_name IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'output_table_name cannot be NULL';
    ELSIF (array_upper(left_table_columns, 1) IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'left_table_columns cannot be an empty array';
    ELSIF (array_upper(right_table_columns, 1) IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'right_table_columns cannot be an empty array';
    ELSIF (array_upper(left_table_columns, 1) <> array_upper(right_table_columns, 1)) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'left_table_columns and right_table_columns must have a matching array length';
    END IF;

    /************************
        TABLE NAMES
    *************************/

    -- create the full name of the left table
    -- the schema name can be NULL which means that the table is temporary
    -- because of this, we need to detect if we should specify the schema
    IF (left_table_schema IS NOT NULL) THEN
        full_left_table = left_table_schema || '.' || left_table_name;
    ELSE
        full_left_table = left_table_name;
    END IF;

    -- create the full name of the right table
    -- the schema name can be NULL which means that the table is temporary
    -- because of this, we need to detect if we should specify the schema
    IF (right_table_schema IS NOT NULL) THEN
        full_right_table = right_table_schema || '.' || right_table_name;
    ELSE
        full_right_table = right_table_name;
    END IF;

    -- create the full name of the output table
    -- the schema name can be NULL which means that the table is temporary
    -- because of this, we need to detect if we should specify the schema
    IF (output_table_schema IS NOT NULL) THEN
        full_output_table = output_table_schema || '.' || output_table_name;
    ELSE
        full_output_table = output_table_name;
    END IF;

    /**********************
        LEFT TABLE
    ***********************/

    -- start to create the table which will store the min values from the left table
    sql =
        'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_null_join_left_table;' || E'\n' ||
        'CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_null_join_left_table AS' || E'\n' ||
        'SELECT';

    -- loop through each column name in the left table column names parameter
    FOR colum_name IN SELECT UNNEST(left_table_columns) LOOP

        -- find the minimum value in this column and subtract one
        -- we will use this as a value we know is not in the column of this table
        sql = sql || E'\n\t' || 'MIN("' || colum_name || '")-1 AS "' || colum_name || '",';

    END LOOP;

    -- remove the trailing comma from the SQL
    sql = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM sql);

    -- finish the SQL to create the left table min values
    sql = sql || E'\n' ||
        'FROM ' || full_left_table || ';';

    -- run the query that creates the table which stores the minimum values for each column in the left table
    EXECUTE sql;

    -- store the sql which will be the return value of the function
    complete_sql = sql;

    /************************
        RIGHT TABLE
    *************************/

    -- start to create the table which will store the min values from the right table
    sql =
        'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_null_join_right_table;' || E'\n' ||
        'CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_null_join_right_table AS' || E'\n' ||
        'SELECT';

    -- loop through each column name in the right table column names parameter
    FOR colum_name IN SELECT UNNEST(right_table_columns) LOOP

        -- find the minimum value in this column and subtract one
        -- we will use this as a value we know is not in the column of this table
        sql = sql || E'\n\t' || 'MIN("' || colum_name || '")-1 AS "' || colum_name || '",';

    END LOOP;

    -- remove the trailing comma from the SQL
    sql = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM sql);

    -- finish the SQL to create the right table min values
    sql = sql || E'\n' ||
        'FROM ' || full_left_table || ';';

    -- run the query that creates the table which stores the minimum values for each column in the right table
    EXECUTE sql;

    -- store the sql which will be the return value of the function
    complete_sql = complete_sql || E'\n\n' || sql;

    -- start to create the final output table which will contain the column names defined in the left_table_columns parameter
    -- each column will contain a negative value that is not present in both the left and right tables for the given column
    sql =
        'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || full_output_table || ';' || E'\n' ||
        'CREATE ' || (CASE WHEN output_table_schema IS NULL THEN 'TEMP ' END) || 'TABLE ' || full_output_table || ' AS' || E'\n' ||
        'SELECT';

    -- loop through each index of the left_table_columns array
    FOR i IN coalesce(array_lower(left_table_columns, 1), 1)..coalesce(array_upper(left_table_columns, 1), 1) LOOP

        -- add to the sql a call to the LEAST function
        -- this function takes an infinite number of columns and returns the smallest value within those columns
        -- we have -1 hardcoded because the smallest minimum value may be a positive integer and so we need to ensure the number used is negative
        -- this way we will not confuse this value with a real ID from a table
        sql = sql || E'\n\t' || 'LEAST(l."' || left_table_columns[i] || '", r."' || right_table_columns[i] || '", -1) AS "' || left_table_columns[i] || '",';

    END LOOP;

    -- remove the trailing comma from the SQL
    sql = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM sql);

    -- finish off the SQL which creates the final table
    sql = sql || E'\n' ||
        'FROM temp_null_join_left_table l' || E'\n' ||
        'CROSS JOIN temp_null_join_right_table r' || ';';

    -- create the final table
    EXECUTE sql;

    -- store the sql which will be the return value of the function
    complete_sql = complete_sql || E'\n\n' || sql;

    -- we no longer need these tables
    sql =
        'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_null_join_left_table;' || E'\n' ||
        'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_null_join_right_table;';
    EXECUTE sql;

    -- store the sql which will be the return value of the function
    complete_sql = complete_sql || E'\n\n' || sql;

    -- return the SQL that has been run, good for debugging purposes or just understanding what the function does
    RETURN complete_sql;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Below is an example usage of the function

```
SELECT pg_temp.get_null_join_int_value
(
    -- left table
    'public', 
    'my_table', 
    '{"column_1", "column_2", "column_3"}', 
    -- right table
    'public', 
    'my_table_aggregations', 
    '{"column_1", "column_2", "column_3"}',
    -- output table
    NULL,
    'temp_null_join_values'
);
```

Once the `temp_null_join_values` table is created you can do a sub select in the join for the `COALESCE` 2nd param.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_result_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_result_table AS
SELECT
    t.record_id,
    agg.aggregation_id
FROM public.my_table t
JOIN my_table_aggregations agg ON
(
    COALESCE(t.column_1, (SELECT column_1 FROM temp_null_join_values)) = COALESCE(agg.column_1, (SELECT column_1 FROM temp_null_join_values)) AND
    COALESCE(t.column_2, (SELECT column_2 FROM temp_null_join_values)) = COALESCE(agg.column_2, (SELECT column_2 FROM temp_null_join_values)) AND
    COALESCE(t.column_3, (SELECT column_3 FROM temp_null_join_values)) = COALESCE(agg.column_3, (SELECT column_3 FROM temp_null_join_values))
);
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Since my solution with NULLIF had performance problems, and your use of COALESCE was much faster, I wonder if you could try tweaking that solution to deal with the issue of -1. To do that, you could try casting to avoid false matches. I'm not sure what the performance hit would be, but it would look like:

```
SELECT
    t.record_id,
    agg.aggregation_id
FROM my_table t
JOIN my_table_aggregations agg ON 
(
    COALESCE(cast(t.column_1 as varchar), 'NA') =
        COALESCE(cast(agg.column_1 as varchar), 'NA') AND
    COALESCE(cast(t.column_2 as varchar), 'NA') =
        COALESCE(cast(agg.column_2 as varchar), 'NA') AND
    COALESCE(cast(t.column_3 as varchar), 'NA') =
        COALESCE(cast(agg.column_3 as varchar), 'NA')
);
```

Comment: It would appear we have found a middle ground. Your first answer took over 10x as long as the original `coalesce` but by adding in the cast to varchar, it takes only 1.5x longer which I think is a decent price to pay. Thank you, I shall be marking this as the anser

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT
    t.record_id,
    a.aggregation_id
FROM my_table t
JOIN my_table_aggregations agg ON
(
    NULLIF(t.column_1, agg.column_1) IS NULL
    AND
    NULLIF(agg.column_1, t.column_1) IS NULL
    AND
    NULLIF(t.column_2, agg.column_2) IS NULL
    AND
    NULLIF(agg.column_2, t.column_2) IS NULL
    AND
    NULLIF(t.column_3, agg.column_3) IS NULL
    AND
    NULLIF(agg.column_3, t.column_3) IS NULL
);
```

Comment: Whilst this works, it suffers the same performance problems as an `OR` does. I dont understand why this is an issue in Postgres...